# Is it possible to Disable deletes on a table on MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I'm using MySQL 5.0 and I would like to know if there's a way to disable deletes on a table. As in, not make it possible for ANY user to delete anything from the tablets, only update and insert.

Comment: yes. Privileges Provided by MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html

Comment: You can certainly make it using the command given here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,290555,290778#msg-290778

Answer (score 25):

Here's an example of a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_table1_del BEFORE DELETE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DELETE cancelled'; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: nice idea about this

Answer (score 9):

Yes, see the MySQL manual [for the GRANT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Here is an example of what you want:

`GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';`

Which gives only `SELECT` and `INSERT` privilages to a specific user/host on a specified table.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `grant` as proposed by others. Or you can create `BEFORE DELETE` trigger that raises an error, so nobody can issue `delete` against your table (keep in mind, it is still possible to `TRUNCATE TABLE`)

Comment: Triggers are cool. Though for something simple like rights restriction, this may result in an increase in WTF delta.

Answer (score 2):

Setting permissions on your table would let you disable the delete operations. You set permissions with [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).